# How do I stop my cursor from sticking to objects in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I've created a game where you must find 3 items, before clicking on the door and winning the game, so theres a few things that stuffing up my game. When you open the game and run it you will see 2 grey rocks on the left hand side, when i click to drag them they stick to the cursor, but when i click the crates to drag them they don't stick, how can i make it like the crates?

```
    stop();

inventorycrowbar_mc.alpha = 0;
inventorypotion_mc.alpha = 0;
inventoryflashlight_mc.alpha = 0;


crowbar_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
potion_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
flashlight_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);


var founditems:Number=0;

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
}

crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate1_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate2_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate3_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate4_mc.buttonMode=true;

boulder1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
boulder1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
boulder1_mc.buttonMode=true;

boulder2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
boulder2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
boulder2_mc.buttonMode=true;

drum3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
drum3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
drum3_mc.buttonMode=true;

grass_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
grass_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
grass_mc.buttonMode=true;

function escapeRoom(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function objectFound(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var inventoryName:String = "inventory" + event.target.name; 
    var inventoryItem:DisplayObject = getChildByName(inventoryName); 
    event.target.alpha = inventoryItem.alpha = 100; 
    founditems ++; 
    event.target.alpha = 0; 
    if(founditems == 3){ 
        door_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, escapeRoom);

    }
}
```

I've attached my flash projection the link below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EnwwKnY8EqbDNSX0JyV01NeTA/view?usp=sharing

The game isn't finished so theres a few messed up things as i needed to re-theme the game,just ignore them. The 3 items to find are flashlight, potion and a red wrench, then click on the door to win.

Comment: Help how? AS3 manual has a timer example and there is google search if you want it explained differently. Even Stackoverflow search has that answer!! No one should have to download an entire project just to look at few lines about drag (how much scrolling? to find it where?). Please show **here** how you drag rocks and how you also drag crates so we can check

Comment: Hi, thanks for that tip, well heres my code below for first the crate, which works fine:


crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate1_mc.buttonMode=true;

then here is the code for the rock(boulder) which follows the cursor and doesn't drop:

boulder1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
boulder1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
boulder1_mc.buttonMode=true;

Comment: @Josh: please don't post code in comments. Add it to your question by editing the question.

Comment: @JoshGomez, okay that's your code and obviously controlled by `pickupObject` function... which you didnt show. Please edit your question to include that. Are using something like `event.currentTarget.startDrag();` to "catch" the target of mouse click? If that's not working well for you then consider using an `enterFrame` function to set both items **x** `= stage.mouseX` and similar for **y** pos etc. Examples in the manual and google.

Comment: so i just added my whole code, sorry guys I'm new to this site :)